# PHP Stripe Script Running Twice

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that processes a stripe payment and increments the donor number upon a successful transaction. However, the script is incrementing by two or sometimes three instead of one. Stripe transactions work. My best understanding is that the page is somehow running twice.

Donor number is saved in a .txt file.
There is no html on the page.
LAMP stack.

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',5);
session_set_cookie_params(5);
session_start();


$unsuccessful = false;
$paid = isset($_SESSION['number']);

//composer requirement for stripe sdk
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("XXXXX");


// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$amount = $_POST['amountInCents'];
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];


try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
        "amount" => $amount,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "card" => $token,
        "description" => "Business Name"
    ]);
} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
  $unsuccessful = true;
    // The card has been declined
}


if($unsuccessful == false){
    #store current donor number in sessioncount.txt
    $file = 'sessioncount.txt';
    $current = (int)file_get_contents($file);
    $new = $current;
    if($paid === false){
      $new = $current + 1;
    }
    $_SESSION['number'] = $new;
    file_put_contents($file, $new);
    header("Location:https://example.com/nextpage.php");
}
```

Comment: Can you not store some sort of reference to the transaction like a transaction ID and check if it's been processed before?

Comment: Looks like stripe can send webhook events.  I will look into implementing this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to know what might be causing the double execution without knowing a little more about the problem. How is this script called? Is somebody pressing a submit button? If so, do you disable the submit button when the user clicks it the first time in order to only submit the request one time in the case that a user "double-clicks"? This is probably the most common cause of double processing for scripts like this. Let me know a little more about the use-case and I can help more.

EDIT: Since you have now tried disabling double submits, try this to help you debug. It may not completely solve the problem, but will help you narrow down if there are multiple requests hitting the script in parallel:

```
<?php
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',5);
session_set_cookie_params(5);
session_start();

$unsuccessful = false;
$paid = isset($_SESSION['number']);

//composer requirement for stripe sdk
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("XXXXX");


// Get the payment token ID submitted by the form:
$amount = $_POST['amountInCents'];
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['processed'])) {
    try {
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            "amount" => $amount,
            "currency" => "usd",
            "card" => $token,
            "description" => "Business Name"
        ]);
    } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
      $unsuccessful = true;
      // The card has been declined
    }


    if($unsuccessful == false){
        #store current donor number in sessioncount.txt
        $file = 'sessioncount.txt';
        $current = (int)file_get_contents($file);
        $new = $current;
        if($paid === false){
          $new = $current + 1;
        }
        $_SESSION['number'] = $new;
        file_put_contents($file, $new);
        header("Location:https://example.com/nextpage.php");

        $_SESSION['processed'] = true;
    }
} else {
    //Put some code here to help you troubleshoot, such as echoing an alert. If this code is executed, it means that something has externally triggered the execution of this script more than once.
}
```

If this doesn't work, it means that the requests for this file are being made in parallel, and something external to the script is causing the file to be executed multiple times.

Comment: Thanks eresourcesfl for reminding me to disable double clicks. Per your suggestion, I disabled the stripe button on double click. However, I have seen the issue occur when I've carefully tested the page with a single click as well. Pursuing webhook events as a work around.

Comment: There are lots of things to troubleshoot, but you should be able to stop multiple executions in several ways. One thing that's easy to do would be to use the session to store a value of $_SESSION['processed'] = true after you successfully process the transaction the first time. Then you can wrap the entire statement in an if(!isset($_SESSION['processed'])) { ... } and that way the code will ONLY execute if it's not already been run previously. I've edited my answer to show an example of this.

Comment: One more thing to note about the double click issue. With Stripe, you often can't just disable the submit button after first click and have that solve your problem. You may ALSO need to disable the default form submission using something like e.preventDefault in javascript. That's because the Stripe form will submit itself automatically after obtaining a valid token. If you don't prevent default, the form will be submitted both when a user clicks and when Stripe gets the token. All this is without knowing what your front end code looks like, but something else to consider for sure.